# DependencyProperty with TwoWay Binding

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, dependency-properties

I have a highly customized Edit control which inherits `RichTextBox`. I needed a way to bind a `Value` to this control, so I registered a new `DependencyProperty`, but I have trouble to code it like I need.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(string), typeof(XliffRichCellEditor),
            new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(XliffRichCellEditor.OnValuePropertyChanged)));
public String Value
{
    get { return (String)this.GetValue(ValueProperty); }
    set { this.SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
}

private static void OnValuePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Need to change Document in  RichTextBox when Binding Source is changed
    // But also ignore if the change comes from RichTextBox which is only updating
    // the DependencyProperty. In this case Binding Source should be updated.
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use can use `UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit` in your Binding statement and get the control of property updation in your hand.

Check this [Thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/c404360c-8e31-4a85-9762-0324ed8812ef/)